# Any uses of JSON-LD?

Tags: linked-data, json

The formal semantic web, now linked data, using RDF is largely flailing in most regions outside the UK. The main problem is the complexity in implementation compared with the tools typically used by web sites, for example, PHP, CSV, MySQL. However, a large part of the world uses Javascript for their development. [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) has emerged as a proposal to tie back end systems together with a widely reusable JSON intermediary based on RDF structure. Are there any significant sites or project that use JSON-LD?

Answer (score 15):

I'm maintaining a list of early adopter in the [JSON-LD Wiki](https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/wiki/Users-of-JSON-LD)

If you want a more visual representation, you might wanna look at http://slideshare.net/lanthaler/building-next-generation-web-ap-is-with-jsonld-and-hydra/34

Answer (score 9):

On the GitHub repo for JSON-LD, they have a [list of users](https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/wiki/Users-of-JSON-LD). Here are three projects from that list and how they use it:

- PaySwarm uses it to "[sign digital contracts](https://payswarm.com/wiki/Faq)"
- graphite.js uses it for "[parsing and serializing](https://github.com/megoth/graphitejs#readme)"
- The Digital Public Library of America API [returns all results](https://github.com/dpla/platform/#readme) in JSON-LD

Answer (score 9):

Google supports [JSON-LD](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/formats/json-ld) for embedding structured data in emails.

From their [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/embedding-schemas-in-emails):

> Gmail, Search Answer Cards, and Google Now rely on structured data in emails to work. Schemas in Gmail supports both JSON-LD and Microdata and you can use either of them to markup information in email. This lets Google understand the fields and provide the user with relevant search results, actions, and cards. For example, if the email is about an event reservation, you might want to annotate the start time, venue, number of tickets, and all other information that defines the reservation.

Comment: Yep, we're looking at JSON-LD within HTML emails as a way to better expose and notify people about information within municipal meeting agendas and public notices. We'll send you an email alert with that Google can pick up and show you in email and importantly Google Now.

Answer (score 7):

The Digital Public Library of America uses JSON-LD

http://dp.la/info/developers/codex/

Comment: Another JSON-LD provider is OpenContext http://opencontext.org/about/services a provider of archeological data

Answer (score 3):

This site used JSON-LD to markup their recipes and successfully got rich snippets in Google:

http://gracessweetlife.com/2010/06/cannoli-siciliani-the-ultimate-italian-pastry/

Example query:
https://www.google.pt/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ikWyVdPPOLLj8wfKrIyABg&gws_rd=ssl#q=grace%27s+cannoli+and+cannoli+filling+recipe

A very important move forward in terms of JSON-LD annotated web.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know what your beef is with this technology, or what it is you think you are critiquing, but it's clear you have something in your head that you think defines a technology.  The use of various linked data approaches has been accepted by such "small" companies as Google, Facebook, Microsoft and Yahoo, and is becoming a mainstay of a number of projects including, but not limited to, Open Data.  If there's a specific criticism that is motivating your question, then I'd suggest doing some homework, understanding what it is you are asking, and being more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Our team is working on the idea of the Semantic Web based on JSON-LD. Since you are interested in this format, you may be interested in learning about the project as well.

[WRIO Internet OS — All You Need is a Browser](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kdKoDfp9mT5M4pssJTqvA6sw4zzYQ5HFaN-osu7J-Nk/edit?usp=sharing) (Google doc)

Answer (score 2):

Current statistics: as of March 2020, JSON-LD is used by ~30% of all the websites.

- https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/da-jsonld/all/all
  (compare https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/structured_data/all)
- https://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/JSON-LD

---

See also: http://webdatacommons.org/structureddata/2019-12/stats/stats.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of informed and spirited debate that took place around Project Open Data - https://github.com/project-open-data/project-open-data.github.io/pull/21.

[Disclaimer - I am a Sr. API Strategist at GSA]

Comment: Gray B., do you mind expanding your answer to include the main points of the debate to prevent link rot and preserve the ideas for posterity?